# Postgresql Multiple index with USING gin

Tags: postgresql

I have to query for example zips_of_state,state_names,county_names from a state table

```
select  zips_of_state,state_names,county_names 
from state 
where zips_of_state='something' 
   OR state_names='something' 
   OR county_names ='something';
```

Now I am indexing as

```
CREATE INDEX ind_zips 
   ON state 
   USING gin(to_tsvector('english', zips_of_state)); -- this works
```

But how do I do multi indexing like

```
CREATE INDEX ind_zips 
   ON state 
   -- this doesn't work
   USING gin(to_tsvector('english', zips_of_state)),state_names, county_names ;
```

Comment: Could you try `CREATE INDEX ind_zips ON state USING gin(to_tsvector('english', zips_of_state),state_names, county_names);`?

Comment: @zedfoxus it doesnt work - ERROR:  data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gin"

Answer (score 1):

That query doesn't match the index at all.

If you don't want full text search, you'll need a regular B-tree index on each of the columns individually, so that you can get a bitmap or.

If you want full text search, write the query as

```
WHERE to_tsvector('english', zips_of_state) ||
      to_tsvector('english', state_names) ||
      to_tsvector('english', country_names)
   @@ to_tsquery('english', 'something')
```

anf use a GIN index on the expression on the left side of the `@@` operator:

```
CREATE INDEX ON stat USING gin ((
   to_tsvector('english', zips_of_state) ||
   to_tsvector('english', state_names) ||
   to_tsvector('english', country_names)
));
```

Comment: Tried this but didnt work. the query time does not see any improvement.

Comment: I have spelled out the `CREATE INDEX`. Is that what you tried?